# why is the hover area so large on this CSS menu?

Tags: css

I have a header nav in which the hover area seems to correspond to the height of the subnav li, and not just the top-level a-tag.

I have no clue why this is happening; the header nav is a copy of the footer nav, which works correctly. Can someone point out what is at work with this header nav?

[link to actual page](http://coffeeonmars.com/suncalc-proto/index.php)

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you're using `opacity` to hide/show the `sub-menu` instead of using `display: block` and `display: none`. You will need to modify your CSS like this:

```
#main_nav ul li ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 1em .2em 0 .4em;
    background: rgb(200,245,190);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgb(120,120,120);
    position: absolute;
    display: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Remove `opacity: 0` from above and use `display: none` instead of `display: hidden` so that it becomes:

```
#main_nav ul li ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 1em .2em 0 .4em;
    background: rgb(200,245,190);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgb(120,120,120);
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

---

```
#main_nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

Remove `opacity: 1` from the CSS above so that it becomes:

```
#main_nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

It should work perfectly after making the above changes.